# Maven: Manually install a Jar from local folder and then go online and grab & install all its dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

In my project's pom file I have a dependency that I can see in [Maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse), **`javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4`** but for some reason I am getting **on some of my computers** the following error while building the project (hence the build fails):

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

1. Any idea why I get this error only on some of my computers (I can say all the computers are using the same network)?
2. Why do I get this error at all? [As far as I can see](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1116874817) the jar **IS** in the maven central repository.
3. Even though maven could not locate/download the jar on some of the computers, I was able to download it manually [through the browser](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1116874817) on these computers. How could it be?
4. Okay, so I've downloaded the jar manually through the browser at one of the problematic computers. I want to install it manually to the local repository on this computer. So from the command line I do:

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.enterprise -DartifactId=cdi-api -Dversion=1.0-SP4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=path/to/file`

...but none of its dependencies has been downloaded as well. Is there some maven plugin to install the file to the local repository **AND** download & install all its dependencies to the local repository?
If so, please show me how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check in the computers where the jar are not downloaded if the settings.xml file present in .m2 folder is having the url of the jar needed. If not add them.
2. You are not able to download because maven searches in the urls defined in the settings.xml file only. So if the url is not present there, even if the jar is in the central repository it wont be downloaded.
3. In your browser you can navigate to that  link and download. Maven wont be able to do it for the reason given in the second point

Answer (score -1):

Ok, looks like you need to mention your repository path in your pom file, What is the url of the repository? is it local to your network or some open url? for example: http://repo2.mvn.org/???

Sample example would be like this::

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
          <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
```

If you could paste the pom file, it would be easier to help you.

To answer your 3 point: Check the settings.xml file in .m2\settings.xml, make sure that same content is present. Sometimes settings.xml are modified directly in maven installation directory. so you better check in that location also.

To Answer your 4th point: mvn install:install installs (in simple terms copies) an artifact (jar/ear/zip/any artifact that meant for distribution) into maven local repository or into remote repository. So in your command, you just tried to install only cdi-api jar.

Whenever you run mvn compile, mvn package, mvn install, maven will scan your pom file and downloads all dependency mentioned into your local repository. I would suggest you to look your local repository and see how is it creating directory structure.

Comment: Isn't the `Unable to find resource ... in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)` evidence that Maven is trying to access that repository but for some reason cannot find the jar there (hence `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` is probably defined as one of the repositorise on this computer)?

Comment: repo2.maven.org is contacted by default. you dont need to mention anywhere in pom.xml or settings.xml. Can you check machines where downloading is giving the trouble are in same domain as other machines too?

Comment: It is possible that your firewall is blocking the download. Well i have this problem. 

There is an quick fix to this problem: copy the entire local respository from the machine where download works fine to the machine where you have the problem. And use maven in offline mode.

Comment: **repo2.maven.org is contacted by default.** - but the jar **IS** there. So why is it not downloaded?

Comment: check your firewall rules.. we had similar problem. It doesnt matter if your in the same domain or network.. It does depends on the proxy server through which it connects..